# Сохранение фокуса выделенного элемента ListView

Tags: c#

Есть следующий код. В listview добавляются процессы. Данный метод вызывается каждые 3 секунды с помощью таймера. Как сделать так, чтобы после обновления фокус оставался на выделенном элементе, если он ещё есть и положение скролла сохранялось?

```
 private void UpdateProcessList()
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                try
                {
                    int index = listView1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName).Index;
                    listView1.Items[index].SubItems.Add(p.Id.ToString());
                    listView1.Items[index].SubItems.Add(p.StartTime.ToShortTimeString());
                    long temp = p.WorkingSet64 / 1024;
                    listView1.Items[index].SubItems.Add(temp.ToString()+" КБ");
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Сразу же находится [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/permanenttan/setting-the-initial-focus-to-a-listview-item):

```
private void FocusAndSelectItem(int itemIndex) 
{ 
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        new FocusAndSelectItemDelegate(TryFocusAndSelectItem),
        DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
        itemIndex); 
}

// Убеждаемся, что айтем находится в видимой области, выделяем его и устанавливаем фокус.
private void TryFocusAndSelectItem(int itemIndex) 
{ 
    ListViewItem lvi = myListView.Items.GetItemAt(itemIndex) as ListViewItem; 
    if (lvi != null) 
    { 
        myListView.ScrollIntoView(lvi); 
        lvi.IsSelected = true; 
        Keyboard.Focus(lvi); 
    } 
}

private delegate void FocusAndSelectItemDelegate(int itemIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем-то основная проблема в данном случае в методе  Clear(), который и сбрасывает этот самый фокус, так как элемент-то удаляется. Я бы лучше посоветовал не перезаполнять весь список, а обновлять его, т.е. после выполнения GetProcesses() проходить по списку и смотреть, а что осталось, а что удалилось. Если же на удалённом элементе стоит фокус, то тут уже логика другая, либо, мол, извиняй, пользователь, нет такого процесса, выбирай другой, либо перемещать курсор на следующий/предыдущий пункт.